# MeteorJS : how find first item in collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In Meteor project, I would like find the first item in a collection. It's for a page with a form in which I can edit the content.

I've created a new collection with my data. How can I target only this item without hardcoding the `_id` in the code (BEURK)?

My router :

```
Router.route('/admin/about/edit', {
    name: 'aboutContentAdmin',
    layoutTemplate: 'adminLayout',
    data: function() {

        var about = About.find().sort({
            x: 1 // doesn't work
        });

        return {
            about: about
        };

    }
});
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To guarantee the order you will need a key to sort on. The `_id` field is not naturally sorted in Meteor. The normal pattern is to add a `createdAt` key of type *Date* and sort on that. You can then limit the return set to a single document to get the *first* document:

```
var about = About.findOne({},{sort: {createdAt: 1}, limit: 1});
```

Comment: Hi ! I've test your var, but i've no result. If i test on my mongo ".find({sort: {createdAt: 1}, limit: 1});", mongo return false. On meteor, if i test this._id on template, it's undefine :(

Answer (score 0):

```
About.findOne({sort: {createdAt: 1}, limit: 1});
```